# Time stamps in header message is always 0

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using ROS Kinetic on Ubuntu linux. For some reason, the time stamps (sec, and nsec values) in the standard header msg always come out as 0.

Does something have to be 'enabled' somewhere?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327077/time-stamps-in-header-message-is-always-0/) by [rRawCWwTKVM](https://answers.ros.org/users/43553/rrawcwwtkvm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-06-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS does not set the header timestamps automatically; the code that publishes the message has to set the timestamp.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2019-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rRawCWwTKVM](https://answers.ros.org/users/43553/rrawcwwtkvm/) on 2019-06-26**:
Ah! haha. Excellent. I thought it was automatically